# How to kill VueJS application running on localhost:8080 (MacOS)

Tags: node.js, macos, express, vue.js, lsof

My environment: MacOS Mojave

I created a VueJS application from their templates using

```
vue init pwa frontend
? Project name frontend
? Project short name: fewer than 12 characters to not be truncated on homescreens (default: same as name)
? Project description A Vue.js project
? Author me@myemail.com
? Vue build runtime
? Install vue-router? Yes
? Use ESLint to lint your code? No
? Setup unit tests with Karma + Mocha? No
? Setup e2e tests with Nightwatch? No

yarn
yarn dev
```

That worked fine. The page ran on localhost:8080 and closed when ctrl-c.

I then built it for production

```
yarn build
```

I wrote a quick JS server to launch the contents from the dist/ folder to see what it looks like after building it.

```
const ora = require('ora')
const chalk = require('chalk');
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const spinner = ora(chalk.yellow("Your application is starting..."));
spinner.start();

var delay = ( function() {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/"));
app.get(/.*/, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
});

app.listen(port);

delay(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/"));
    app.get(/.*/, function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
    });
}, 3000);

spinner.stop();
console.log(chalk.cyan("Your application is running here: ") + ("http://localhost:8080"));
```

I run the server `node server.js`

However when I ctrl-c it kills the script however the application is still running on localhost:8080

I have tried `sudo lsof -i tcp:8080` and `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8080` and they both returned nothing. Which leaves me with the following question: How do I stop this from listening on port 8080?

Comment: Try this command `lsof -ti:8080 | xargs kill -9`

Comment: Does not work as lsof -ti:8080 doesn't return any results.

Comment: How are you determining it's still running?

Comment: I am going to http://localhost:8080 and the application is still running.

Comment: Can you try `npx kill-port 8080`?

Comment: @AlicanBalik I ran the command it is still running. I don't understand what the issue is

Comment: I’ve experienced the same a few times (not specific to vue only). No process using the port, but the browser was rendering the page still. In my case a force reload of the browser correctly resulted in a “could not connect” page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, I found out the problem. I had to go to `chrome://serviceworker-internals` and `chrome://appcache-internals`. I did a search  for `localhost:8080` and killed those serviceworkers.

I hope this helps whoever this happens to next!